# Pygame and Multiprocessing Strategy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pygame

I'm developing a game in pygame and i don't know which tasks should go to which process.

I have two processes connected by a pipe, one will have the window another will do calculations.

My question is: **Which parts of the main loop should go to the other process?**

In my game i will have to do event handling, collision detection, AI, drawing and heavy calculations(2D lighting system).

I'm afraid that if i put to much stuff on the other process the main one will have to wait for input and the FPS will freeze.

PS: For now i'm just starting to code the game so i can't show you much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [the observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

I would suggest the following architecture for creating a PyGame with two processes:

You divide your program into two parts:

1. **model**

   all the game logic is kept in the subprocess, computing the whole game.
   Whenever there is something noteworthy changed, it notifies the other process.

   responsibilities:

   - update the game e.g. in a loop
   - do physics
   - send updates to the gui
2. **gui**

   The gui is in the main process because it starts several games.
   When a game is started it starts to observe important parts of the game.

   responsibilities

   - handle user input e.g. right arrow pressed
   - send modifications to the model e.g. player walks righth
   - render views of model elements when updates are received

Note that I do not really know much of PyGame. 
But keeping model and view apart is possible.

You can have a look at the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), too. But it is really heavy. Just merging View and Controller is enough if the program shall not be distributed across computers.

Then I heard about [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM). Not sure whether this is too much again since you only need to split your game into two parts and not three.

Comment: Let me get this strait. In the main process i only do the drawing with the information i get from the other process and in the sub-process i get events from the main process, do event handling, calculate 'drawing information' and send it(maybe not in this order).

Comment: "Let me get this strait. In the main process i only do the drawing with the information i get from the other process and in the sub-process" - yes